# Entry doesn't adopts LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand in horizontal context

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to use an **expanding** `Entry` and a `Button` in a horizontal `StackLayout`:

```cs
var item = new StackLayout { 
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Children = {

        new Entry { 
            Placeholder = "Feldtitel",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand // NOTE THIS
        },
        new Button{ 
            Text = CFieldDescription.getNameForFieldType( fieldType ),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End
        }

    }};
```

While the `Entry` is at the start, the `Button` is at the end, [Xamarin.Forms](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/) **doesn't change the size of `Entry` to fill the horizontal space**:

[image]

**Do I need to change my code? Or did I find a bug?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change the `Entry.HorizontalOptions` to `LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` to get the desired effect:

```cs
var item = new StackLayout { 
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Spacing = 12, //you probably want this
    Children = {
        new Entry { 
            Placeholder = "Feldtitel",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand //there, fixed
        },
        new Button{ 
            Text = CFieldDescription.getNameForFieldType( fieldType ),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End
        }
    }};
```

It looks like the `LayoutOptions` needs some good documentation.

Comment: `Button` has the same problem. But after change it to `FillAndExpand` The `Button.Text` also only display on the middle, not from left.  Is there any way to fix it too? Thank you.

Comment: @qakmak Try `StartAndExpand`

Comment: @Boris `StartAndExpand` doesn't expand the button, when it has a padding :/